# Tap Detection data conversion for ADXL345 sensor

Tags: arduino, hex, arduino-ide, adc, assembly-resolution

I am interfacing [ADXL345](https://store.ncd.io/product/adxl345-3-axis-accelerometer-13-bit-i2c-mini-module/) sensor by using the [datasheet](https://media.ncd.io/sites/2/20170721134832/ADXL345.pdf) as well as other libraries I am able to under stand the setup of TAP threshold.

I need to confirm that in [example code](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/adxl345-hookup-guide#example-code) :

```
// Set values for what is considered a TAP and what is a DOUBLE TAP (0-
 255)
adxl.setTapThreshold(50);           // 62.5 mg per increment
adxl.setTapDuration(15);            // 625 μs per increment
adxl.setDoubleTapLatency(80);       // 1.25 ms per increment
adxl.setDoubleTapWindow(200);       // 1.25 ms per increment
```

in which user setup values which is mentioned according to scale factor as per mentioned in datasheet, 
I am facing doubt here and need to clear this

1. the values mentioned for Tap solution is decimal or hexadecimal values ?
2. Need to know the conversion formulae which is used to create for setup the threshold.

As ADXL345 sensor which, I am using has maximum resolution of 13 bits so I want to set the value as per 13 bits

Any suggestion advice regarding this will be very helpful for me to work on ADXL345 sensor interfacing with an Arduino

Answer (score 0):

The values are decimal values - you can see in the comments how they relate to actual physical values:

```
adxl.setTapThreshold(50);           // 62.5 mg per increment -> 62.5mg * 50 = 3.125g
adxl.setTapDuration(15);            // 625 μs per increment -> 625us * 15 = 9.375ms
adxl.setDoubleTapLatency(80);       // 1.25 ms per increment -> 1.25ms * 80 = 100ms
adxl.setDoubleTapWindow(200);       // 1.25 ms per increment -> 1.25ms * 200 = 250ms
```

So to work out the value you need for a threshold of Xg, use the formula

```
v = X / 62.5mg = X / 0.0625
```

For example, for a threshold of 5g:

```
adxl.setTapThreshold(80); // Because 5 / 0.0625 = 80
```

Comment: hey, thanks a lot for the reply I have coded as per the way you suggested, but to get the output I have to compare these parameters with normal axis(x,y,z) values?

Comment: I am using this conversion to check the values of X Y Z axis
     https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/ADXL345/blob/master/Arduino/ADXL345.ino